# How to implement autohide task panel in android

Tags: android

I want to implement video panel in android in which i want to create a task panel which contain command such like play, pause. i have created a layout for this is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:id="@+id/layout">
<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/timer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top|left"
    android:textColor="@color/RED"
    android:text="HI"></TextView>
    <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/rLayoutCameraButtons" 

    android:layout_gravity="center|bottom">
        <SeekBar
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10px"
            android:id="@+id/seekbar"
            android:max="100"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        />
        <RelativeLayout
         android:id="@+id/rlayout_buttons"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_below="@+id/seekbar"
         >
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/buttonPlay" 
            android:text="Play" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_centerInParent="true">
        </Button>
        <Button 
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
            android:id="@+id/buttonStop" 
            android:text="Stop" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </Button>
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/buttonPause" 
            android:text="Pause" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >
        </Button>
        </RelativeLayout>           
    </RelativeLayout>
```

i want to hide auto hide my relative layout withing 5 sec from the last touch on that
also i want to make it appear on touch on that area where it existed. not getting any idea
plz help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you aware of [`MediaController`](http://d.android.com/reference/android/widget/MediaController.html)? If you don't need to customize your panel too much, it's the simple and elegant solution you're looking for. You can simply start with:

```
myVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
```

[Here](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Gallery3D.git;a=blob;f=src/com/cooliris/media/MovieViewControl.java;h=06f604396c8d40267f059d672ff2ee770f874ed5;hb=HEAD)'s an example of the `MediaController` being used in the 3D Gallery app.

Answer (score 0):

May be ViewStub can be useful. Check it out if it fits in your requirement ...

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-stubs.html

Answer (score 0):

One of the approaches that you can try:
1. Intercept the `onTouchEvent` in your activity that hosts the player
2. on Touch Up post a delayed message to a `Handler` created on UI thread, that will hide the parent layout of the panel.
3. Remember/determine the area where parent Layout of the panel is drawn. Inside on Touch, write a logic to decide if Touch occurred in area of interest, if so, make the panel visible.

Hope that helps.